Grub 2.12 Saving or Custom bootloader
Changing the value of grub 2 12 and saving it without the original grub.cfg file . Thanks using lfs and have to append root=/dev/sda1 ro rootdelay=5 to my bootscript and dont know how on LFS 11.3

Please [edit] your question and add some more information: 1. Ask a question. There is no question here, what do you need from us? 2. Explain what you are trying to do and why so we can understand. What value do you want to change? Where?  3. Tell us what you have tried so far and how it failed so we don't waste your time with solutions you have already attempted. 4. Tell us your operating system. Does the apparently random "Thanks LFS 11.3" imply you are using Linux from scratch? Please clarify.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
